# FIX protocol : ClearingBusinessDate field

Tags: fix-protocol

I have a questions about FIX protocol.
I plan to send a PositionReport message without a PositionReportRequest message received. But i must fill a field, ClearingBusinessDate, in the PositionReport message that i do not know what is the purpose of that field. Altough the PositionReportRequest has that field, i will not get a request message before sending a report message. So, i have no idea what it should be. And the worst thing is it is a required field..
What should be the value of ClearingBusinessDate field?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more a question for your counterparty than a question about general FIX protocol.

If you're connecting to an outside FIX counterparty (e.g. exchange, clearing firm, etc), they should have documentation on their interface that should describe what the expected fields and field values should be.  If they don't have docs, then you'll have to ask them.

FIX is a very loose protocol.  All of the messages and fields in the default message/field definitions are really just suggestions.  In practice, most counterparties alter and mutilate these message/field definitions in numerous ways.  They may add custom fields, change field types, make optional fields required and vice versa, remove fields, etc etc.  I've never seen a counterparty *not* mess with the definitions.

(P.S. You have a very low answer-acceptance rate.  Please consider going back over your past questions and accepting the best answers.  You'll get rep points, and you'll make StackOverflow better.)